# Most compact/efficient/maintainable way to add these anonymous classes

Tags: java

Here is my interface:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Function
{
    private String name;
    private String result;
    public Function(String name, String result)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public abstract Thing execute(Cheesepuff cheesepuff, int line, ArrayList<Thing> arguments) throws CheesepuffException;
}
```

And currently I have a whole file full of these declarations:

```
addDefaultFunction(functions,
        new Function("get", "Gets the variable named by arg1.")
        {
            @Override
            public Thing execute(Cheesepuff cheesepuff, int line, ArrayList<Thing> arguments) throws CheesepuffException
            {
                assertMinimumArguments(1, arguments, line, this);
                assertNotNull(arguments.get(0), 1, line, this);                 

                return cheesepuff.getVariable(arguments.get(0).getString(line));                        
            }            
        });
```

**Is there a more compact way to do this?** No is an acceptable answer. It just seems like there's a ton of extra code adding bloat to it.

In C# for example you could do this:

```
addDefaultFunction(functions, "get", "Gets the variable named by arg1.",
   (Cheesepuff cheesepuff, int line, List<Thing> arguments) =>
    {
        .....
    });
```

Or something like that. I don't remember the exact syntax... and obviously the implementation would be slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 is going to have lambda expressions, which have a similar syntax as in your C# example.

Unfortunately, you're going to have to wait a bit as JDK 8 is [scheduled for release this Spring](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/). You can already [try out a snapshot release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and have a go with [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).